# Pytorch mask tensor with boolean numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, torch

I have a `84x84` pytorch tensor named `target`. I need to mask it with an `84x84` boolean numpy array which consists of `True` and `False`.

When I do `target = target[mask]`, I get the error `TypeError: can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.bool_. The only supported types are: double, float, float16, int64, int32, and uint8.`

Surprisingly, I get this error only when running on a GPU. When running on a CPU, everything works fine. How can I fix this?

Comment: What about the answer provided here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/equivalent-of-numpy-ma-array-to-mask-values-in-pytorch/53354 ?

Comment: [convert it to np.uint8](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/cant-convert-np-ndarray-of-type-numpy-bool/32669)

Comment: It would be great if you would provide a minimal example.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is some confusion with the types. But this works.

```
import torch
tensor = torch.randn(84,84)
c = torch.randn(tensor.size()).bool()
c[1, 2:5] = False
x = tensor[c].size()
```

For testing I created a tensor with random values. Afterwards 3 elements are set to False. In the last step I look get the size 7053 resulting from 84^2 - 3.

Hope that helps somehow.